# PHP regex expression for preg_split with multiple periods

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have some text which I need to split into 2 elements based on delimiters "-:." (dash, colon or period) 
The below works for me :

```
$exploded_val = preg_split( "/[-:\.]/", $orig_val );
```

Problem is that some of the text have multiple periods, in which case it doesn't work. Can you help please?
example text 
"Statue of Liberty....North America"
"Leaning tower-pisa"
"great wall:china"

Comment: `/[-:\.]+/` adding the `+` will make the expression match 1 or more.

Comment: If it is only multiple periods that you are after, you can try /([-:]|\.+)/

Comment: Btw, you need a double back-slash in front of the period when it is in a string.

Comment: @goldmine: but you need _none_ in a character class ;)